# Jtable drag selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have an application that uses JTable and has this selected:

```
        //The line below is setting ptm (AbstractTableModel instance) as the 
        //parameter for a new JTable instance.
            table = new JTable(ptm);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        //This is setting user selection to a single interval.
            table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Single_Interval_Selection. But I don't want to be able to drag the mouse and select multiple rows. How can I or whats the best approach to disabling the mouse drag on rows!

I thought of implementing MouseMotionListener which I thought was the best approach.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html

This is how I solved the situation. I ended up finding out that their is a bug with adding a mouse listener to a jScrollPane. Instead you must add it to the view of the panel. You have to add the listener to the parent UI of the JTable.

```
        scroll.getViewport().getView().addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Mouse has been dragged");

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
```

Comment: Why would you care how the user makes the selection?

Comment: I think that it gives a more professional feeling to the application. A lot of apps won't let you drag for multiple selections but hold down ctrl and click. Look at the Eclipse IDE you can't drag to select multiple classes but you can ctrl + click.

Comment: I'd be reluctant to foreclose mouse selection; this is handled by the table's UI delegate, typically a subclass of `BasicTableUI`; you might look at how the default works.

Comment: @trashgod.....I thought that your last comment was a bit confusing based on how you worded it. But now I understand what you mean after I did a lot of research on the java api.